# Get PID form siginfo_t in c

Tags: c, signals, handler

i'm trying to use siginfo_t to know the PID of the process that sent the signals. I red many documentation but i don't understand what is the correct path to get the PID.

in main:

```
struct sigaction action;
memset(&action, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
action.sa_sigaction = UserTerminationNotified;  
sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask); /* block sigs of type being handled */
action.sa_flags = SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO; /* restart syscalls if possible */
sigaction(2, &action,NULL);
```

function:

```
void UserTerminationNotified(int sig, siginfo_t* info, void* vp){
   printf("eccolo: %d",info->_sifields._sigchld->si_pid);  this give me back error but i wrote to specifie where i'm in troble
exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `info->si_pid`? See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html for the structure of `siginfo_t`.

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I don't know why but when i tried vs code underlined it in red.

Comment: Note that neither `printf()` nor `exit()` are safe to call from a signal handler.  POSIX only allows *async-signal-safe* functions to be called from a signal handler, and neither `printf()` nor `exit()` are async-signal-safe.  Read the [Linux `signal-safety` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).  (Note that man page is wrong about `fork()` - `fork()` is broken in glibc and an attempt to get it removed from the POSIX async-signal-safe requirement was made about 15 years ago. POSIX response was something like "Nah. That isn't too hard for everyone else...")