# Get Pid of the process that sent the signal in golang

Tags: go

I have a `golang` script that traps the signal and does some work. I would like to understand if is there a way to gather the PID of process that sent the relevant signal

Reason we need a way to know who sent to signal so as to take better decision on what to do.

I see there is API in `*nix` to do that. (https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/man-pages/siginfo_t.3type.en) also can be see here [Get PID form siginfo_t in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73062538/get-pid-form-siginfo-t-in-c)

But unfortunately I'm not that proficient in C to do that. Any way this can be achieve in golang.